# scala - regular expression

Tags: regex, scala

I am new to scala. I am not new to regular expression, but scala's regular expression is a bit confusing to me. For example, my input variable is string from the "DEVICE" column

[image]

I would like to convert input with name from upper group to "TABLET", from middle group to "DESKTOP", and rest to "PHONE", like following. What is most elegant way to do it?

```
"IOSTABLET" => "TABLET"
"ANDROIDTABLET" => "TABLET"
"TABLET"  => "TABLET"
"SAFARI" => "DESKTOP"
...
```

Here is my solution using pattern matching

```
val tablet = """.*(TABLET)$""".r
val phone = """.*(PHONE)$""".r


"IOSTABLET" match {
  case tablet(device) => "TABLET"
  case phone(device) => "PHONE"
  case _ => "DESKTOP"
}
```

Comment: In my option because Scala is functional the most elegant way is pattern matching [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: There is a type in your code example, probably the reason you're getting a wrong value out - `val tablet = """.*(TABLE)$""".r` should be TABLET instead of TABLE, since you're specifying that it ends with that word ($)

Comment: that is right! 囧...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val myDevice = "IOSTABLET"

val translated = myDevice match {
   case "IOSTABLET" | "ANDROIDTABLET" | "TABLET" => "TABLET"
   case "SAFARI" | "IE" => "DESKTOP"
   case "etc" | "etc2" => "etc3"
}
```

Something like that is probably the cleanest approach. You can use a regex but its probably not warranted here.

Comment: thanks! It works. But since more "DEVICE" types may be added later, a regex implementation is still preferred